# Install packages into encrypted partition in kickstart?

Tags: fedora, kickstart

I've followed [this](https://blog.laimbock.com/2014/12/27/howto-kickstart-fedora-with-luks-encrypted-partitions/) blog post which details how to create a luks encrypted partition in a kickstart which works great to encrypt a partition.

The partition I'm attempting to encrypt should be mounted as `/var/lib` which some of the packages I install in the `%packages` section of my kickstart install into.

The issue that I'm having is that the encrypted partition does not appear to be mounted before the packages in the `%packages` section are installed. This means that `/var/lib` is being created (and installed into) under my root partition rather than my encrypted partition.

Is there any way to make sure the encrypted partition is mounted to `/var/lib` before the packages are installed as part of the kickstart? What section should this happen in?

Comment: ...why not just use `partition --encrypted --passphrase PASS [etc.] /var/lib`, as per the [Kickstart documentation](http://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#part-or-partition)?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here... OK so here is what I have found:

**ks.cfg way to do it:**

This is right according to the documentation (how I read it...):

```
part / --size=8000 --grow --fstype=ext4 --encrypted --passphrase=somepassword
```

**End result:**

```
/dev/vda6 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

Lovely unencrypted free for all to see! :)

**Solution:**

You have to mix ks.cfg and preseed files to get it to work on Ubuntu (Debian and Redhat automation techniques). I must say that I am a bit confused as to why Canonical has chosen this way... but most of the documentation that I have found suggests both ks.cfg and ks.preseed files in automating Ubuntu installs. Please note that if you use the mini.iso (net install) you can use only the ks.preseed and follow the Debian documentation entirely (I have done this extensively). To solve your problem above: you must add the below to your ks.preseed file below "DISK Configuration".

The installer will mount the filesystem and install the OS. At the end, you can use the %packages instruction if you like I presume -- but if you need to control more please consider using the preseed file again:

**MODIFY THE INSTALLED SYSTEM:**

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    # the root filesystem is in /target
    mkdir -p /target/opt/scripts; \ 
    # in-target executes everything as if you were in the new system.
    in-target chmod +x /opt/rtd/scripts/post-install.sh; \
```

**DISK Configuration:**

```
# --------------------------------------------------- #
#   Disk layout   
# --------------------------------------------------- #
#
## Set option to encrypt the hard disk:
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto

# Option to temporarily set full disk encryption password to automate the install below. 
# If you prefer to be propmpted during the system installation process comment out the 
# two crypto/passphrase options below. The disk encryption password can be changed at 
# anytime once the system is installed using the following command: 
#
#       tool      :   command   : device and partition number
#               cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/sda4 
#
#
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase password plaintextpassword-or-encrypted
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again password plaintextpassword-or-encrypted

# When disk encryption is enabled, skip wiping the partitions beforehand since it takes too much time.
d-i partman-auto-crypto/erase_disks boolean false
# Delete anything on the first hard drive, then define the actual layout of the disk 
# using and encrypted LVM volume for security. 
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm_span boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string crypt
# Use generic instead of vda & sda to ensure recipie is applied even if this install is run in KVM, vmware, virtualbox IDE or SATA.
# d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sdb 
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-encrypted
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      root-encrypted ::                                       \
                    538 538 1075 free                         \
                    $primary                                  \
                    $iflabel{ gpt }                           \
                    $reusemethod{ }                           \
                    method{ efi } format{ }                   \
              .                                               \
              500 500 500 ext3                                \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
                                                              \
              .                                               \
              2000 2000 2000 linux-swap                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ swap }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ root }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              2000 2000 2000 ext4                             \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ keep }                          \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      label{ rescuedisk }                     \
              .

d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_mount_point boolean false
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
# --------------------------------------------------- #
```